# Remove unwanted characters from a list over a for loop

Tags: python

I have a list here and I want to remove all the unwanted characters leaving only the resolution. The information changes depending on the source so I can't have a constant variable.

```
Source = ['First link: Resolution:1920x1080', 'Second Link: Resolution:1280x720', 'Third Link: Available - Resolution:960x720']
```

I want to strip all the characters except for the true resolution

```
Source = ['1920x1080', '1280x720', '960x720']
```

I literally have no way to come across this, help would be appreciated

Comment: Split on colons? RegEx for "digits'x'digits"?

Comment: `Source = [s.split(':')[-1] for s in Source]` ?

Comment: I found out a method but it's very unpythonic. I just kept splitting with constant strings

Comment: Then give a [mcve] and explain the problem.

Comment: You don't _literally_ have no way to overcome this, it can be done. What did you actually try?

Comment: Rather than trying to "remove unwanted characters", you should think about how to get just the characters you want. I suggest you read about parsing a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need `re`, it's built-in module.

```
import re

links = ['First link: Resolution:1920x1080', 'Second Link: Resolution:1280x720', 'Third Link: Available - Resolution:960x720']
resolutions = []
for link in links:
    result = re.search('(\d+x\d+)', link)
    if result is not None:
        resolutions.append(result.group(0))

print(resolutions)
```

Result:

```
['1920x1080', '1280x720', '960x720']
```

If resolution always at the end of the string you can add `$` to the end of regex `'(\d+x\d+)$'`

Comment: Could you care to explain line 6 for me please? Thanks

Comment: @Awais Scan through string looking for the first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object. Return None if no position in the string matches the pattern.

Comment: @Awais '(\d+x\d+)' is regular expression for the resolutions

Answer (score 0):

This uses 3rd party luapatt (pip install luapatt):

```
Source = [
  'First link: Resolution:1920x1080',
  'Second Link: Resolution:1280x720',
  'Third Link: Available - Resolution:960x720'
  ]

import luapatt as lua
Source = [lua.match(x,'%d+x%d+') for x in Source]

print(Source)
```

Output:

```
['1920x1080', '1280x720', '960x720']
```

Comment: There's just no need for another library, it can be done with simple python in this case

Comment: I didn't say it couldn't.

Comment: So why recommend another dependency that uses regex, rather than the simple approach?

Comment: Because I personally like Lua patterns (they're not regex).  The OP is looking for a solution.  So, here's one.  I bet there are thousands more.  You can offer yours.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex. It's really simple if you just split the string with `:`

```py
ss = ['First link: Resolution:1920x1080', 'Second Link: Resolution:1280x720', 'Third Link: Available - Resolution:960x720']
output = []
for s in ss:
    out.append(s.split(':')[-1]) # [-1] is the last item of a List
```

---

even simpler if you use list comprehension - just one line

```py
output = [s.split(':')[-1] for s in ss] # ss is your input list
```

Answer (score 0):

---edit---

I came across this question by searching LUA, so i gave the answer in LUA. But it seems this question is not about how to write in lua, sorry for that.

---edit---

Why do you need 3rd party library?
just use string.match

```lua
local Source = {'First link: Resolution:1920x1080', 'Second Link: Resolution:1280x720', 'Third Link: Available - Resolution:960x720'}

local output = {}

for i,v in ipairs(Source) do
    table.insert(output, string.match(v, "(%d+x%d+)"))
end

for i,v in ipairs(output) do
    print(i,v)
end
```

Answer (score -1):

This snippet uses the fact that actual resolution is at the end of every string:

```
Source = [link[link.find("Resolution:")+11:] for link in Source]

print(Source)
# ['1920x1080', '1280x720', '960x720']
```